# CMS static block not displaying preview in admin panel Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, ce-1.9.0.1, wysiwyg, tinymce

Magento admin panel not displaying preview of images and texts like cms-admin-preview.png

[image]

It is now displaying like this in cms-admin-not-preview.png

[image]

If anyone has faced this issue then please help me solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the 'Show/Hide Editor' button to toggle raw HTML markup and visual elements.

Comment: I clicked on **show/hide editor** but it still does not show the preview. Also at first it shows me all the option of editor like **Insert image, widget** ect.

Comment: You can change the default setting for whether the editor is enabled or disabled in `System > Configuration > GENERAL > Content Management > Enable WYSIWYG Editor`. If it does not show the editor by toggling that button, you'll have to check the console log in your browser for errors.